# Magento Connect Strange Upload Issue

Tags: magento-connect, downloader

i have a strange problem in magento connect, no upload option works, the fields seem kind of off, see the image.

[image]

I am running Nginx, FastCGI-Hhvm, i installed a Wordpress and everything works fine, including installed plugins and themes using upload function without any problem.

using upload in CMS pages or adding a product all working fine except Magento Connect.

I already tried:

1. Set permissions 777
2. Run Magento Clean Up
3. Setting correct chown

Comment: Instead of 777, try using 644 for files and 755 for directories if your server is running SuPHP or SuExec.

Answer (score 1):

The inputs are disabled if the method `Maged_Controller::isWritable` returns `false` or `null`.
The class is found in the file `downloader/Maged/Controller.php`.
The method looks like this:

```
public function isWritable()
{
    if (is_null($this->_writable)) {
        $this->_writable = is_writable($this->getMageDir() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR)
            && is_writable($this->filepath())
            && (!file_exists($this->filepath('config.ini') || is_writable($this->filepath('config.ini'))));
    }
    return $this->_writable;
}
```

Check which ones of the conditions returns `false`.

Answer (score 0):

I could not get Directory permissions '755' to work. so try '775' instead and see if that works. The second bit gives group white permissions, but it is not much more secure then '777'. From command line do `find . -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \;` in the directory (folder) you want to change.